Set React-Native navigator to show a BottomTab on all pages
I have a BottomTab(BottomTabsNavigator()) defined which is working, but as soon as I navigate from a page to another using
<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Patient')} />

then on the landing page(Patient here) the BottomTab is gone. I like this BottonTabNavigator to appear in all pages I navigate to. see the App.js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomTabsNavigator(){
    return (
            <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" 
                component={HomeScreen} 
            />
            </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

function AuthenticatedStack() {
    return (
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.blueHeader },
                    headerTintColor: Colors.orangeClear,
                }}
            >
            <Stack.Screen 
                name="BottomTabs"
                component={ BottomTabsNavigator }
                options={{
                    headerShown: false, 
                }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                        name="Patient"
                        component={Patient}
                options={{
                    title: "Patient"
                }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
            <>
                <NavigationContainer>
                     <AuthenticatedStack />
                </NavigationContainer>
            </>
    );
}

Any hint, thank you.

The Patient screen is not within BottomTabsNavigator

I found out. By creating a stack navigator for each tab in the bottom tab navigator, we can ensure that the bottom tab bar remains visible while navigating to different screens within each tab's stack.
function HomeStack() {
    return (
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.blueHeader },
                    headerTintColor: Colors.orangeClear,
                }}
            >
            <Stack.Screen 
                name="home"
                component={home}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                 name="home1"
                 component={home1}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

function PatientStack() {
    return (
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.blueHeader },
                    headerTintColor: Colors.orangeClear,
                }}
            >
            <Stack.Screen 
                name="patient"
                component={patient}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                 name="addPatient"
                 component={addPatient}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                 name="deletePatient"
                 component={deletePatient}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

function BottomTabsNavigator(){
    return (
            <Tab.Navigator>
                 <Tab.Screen name="HomeTab" 
                     component={HomeStack} 
                 />
                 <Tab.Screen name="PatientTab" 
                     component={PatientStack} 
                 />
            </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

function AuthenticatedStack() {
    return (
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.blueHeader },
                    headerTintColor: Colors.orangeClear,
                }}
            >
            <Stack.Screen 
                name="BottomTabs"
                component={ BottomTabsNavigator }
                options={{
                    headerShown: false, 
                }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
            <>
                <NavigationContainer>
                     <AuthenticatedStack />
                </NavigationContainer>
            </>
    );
}

